# asp.net c# codefile not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a codefile to my asp.net masterpage. I had it working properly on an individual page, but cannot do so on my master page.

In my aspx master page I have:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Master.cs" Inherits="Master.Master" %>
```

Then I have a file called:

```
Master.cs
```

and the code below is:

```
namespace Master
{
    using System;

    public partial class Master : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("ALEX");
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

as far as I can see all my declarations are correct, but the error I get is:

```
ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).
```

and the line:

```
Line 5:      public partial class Master : System.Web.UI.Page
```

is in red. I have had this error before but I am sure I have all my code correctly, so am not sure why I m getting this error?

Maybe the master file needs a different setup, or it works differently on the masterpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a master page code behind class, the base class to inherit is `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`, not `System.Web.UI.Page`.